# Ubuntu 12.04 desktop joining a Windows Server 2012 domain - not working

Tags: ubuntu, dns, windows-server-2012, dhcp

I have DHCP, DNS and AD DS running on my Windows Server 2012. I have configured a domain and all my clients are able to join it, which are: Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 SERVER. Although when i try to join the domain with my Ubuntu 12.04 DESKTOP i am not able to join.

I tried using the terminal and tried using the likewise application, both failed. It says it is unable to find the .local extension. Im using the .local extension since im doing this project for school.

Is anybody able to help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure /etc/resolv.conf points to your dns server.

I've had success with http://www.powerbrokeropen.org/ on debian and centos.